# Xcode 9 invalid top margin position for my collectionView in iPhone larger than 5s

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, margin, ios11, xcode9

i'm creating a simple UI for my profile scene, i use collectionview and i set the top constraints to equals to superview ( 0 ).

This works fine in my iPhone 5S ( 4 inch iphone), but, in my iPhone 7, 8, 8 plus ( 4.7 & 5.5 inch), my collectionview top position is moved to below my transparent navigation bar, what should i do?

i use this code to transparent my navigation bar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {        
    let bar = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar)!
    bar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    bar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    bar.isTranslucent = true
    AnalyticsHelper.track(screen)
}
```

here's my sample screenshoot

4 Inch iPhone looks good and it starts at y=0
[image: iphone 5s looks good and fine with 0 of top constraints]

4.7 iphone and 5.5 iphone is weird because it starts at y=64
[image: invalid top position for 4.7 inch and 5.5 inch]

and if i check my offset in func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView), i got 0 as a start offset in iphone 5s, but in larger iphone, it got -64 as a start offset, why this could happen ?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem by select content insets to never in my CollectionView Size inspector (The ruler icon, 2nd icon from the right)